# Firestore Uncaught TypeError: doc.data is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

When i want to display data from firestore in node.js html, i got an error on this 2 codes: **productName.textContent = doc.data().name;** and
**productPrice.textContent = doc.data().price;**

[image: browser console]
[image: firestore]

```
const myProducts = db.collection('products');
const productsContainer = document.querySelector('#groceries');

 function renderProduct(doc) {
   const docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
   let article = document.createElement('article');
   let productName = document.createElement('h4');
   let productPrice = document.createElement('p');

   article.setAttribute('id', doc.id);
   productName.textContent = doc.data().name;
   productPrice.textContent = doc.data().price;

   docFrag.appendChild(productName);
   docFrag.appendChild(productPrice);

   article.appendChild(docFrag);
   productsContainer.appendChild(article);
 }

 myProducts.onSnapshot(products => {
   products.forEach(doc => {
     products = doc.data();
     console.log(products);
     renderProduct(products);
   });
 });

 class shop extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app-wrapper">
                <ContainerHeader match={this.props.match} title={<IntlMessages id="appModule.contactSupport"/>}/>
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div id="groceries"></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're passing data, not a doc reference to `renderProduct`, so you just access the props directly:

```
function renderProduct(data) {
   // ...
   article.setAttribute('id', data.id);
   productName.textContent = data.name;
   productPrice.textContent = data.price;
   // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is passing the raw JavaScript data into `renderProduct`:

```
 products = doc.data();
 console.log(products);
 renderProduct(products);
```

It's already calling `doc.data()` to get that object.  But then the function goes on to keep calling `data()` on that same object:

```
productName.textContent = doc.data().name;
productPrice.textContent = doc.data().price;
```

Just remove the extra calls to `data()`.  You probably also might want to rename the parameter from `doc` to `data` to make it more clear what it's expecting.

```
productName.textContent = doc.name;
productPrice.textContent = doc.price;
```

Comment: now i get this error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null**
on `productsContainer.appendChild(article);`

How do i solve that?